# FreeSWITCH - Insert only 1 call leg CDR

Tags: freeswitch

I am trying to bridge two legs using *uuid_bridge* and everything is working OK except CDR.
It is inserting to DB table v_xml_cdr the details for the first UUID.
uuid_bridge ***uuid_leg_a*** uuid_leg_b.

Comment: You need to explain better. What is your problem and what you want to achieve?

Comment: I am using the uuid_bridge function to bridge 2 legs. After using the function and making the call, I can see only 1 CDR written into DB. When I check the DB to see which leg data was inserted, I can see only the first one that I used in that command. uuid_bridge ${uuid_leg_a} ${uuid_leg_b}. When I check the CDR CSV log, /var/log/freeswitch/cdr-csv/Master.csv, I can see  both queries, leg a and b.

Comment: Are you using mod_odbc_cdr? Can you put your config file for it if you are using it?

Comment: So how you write CDRs to DB, if you are not using mod_odbc_cdr?

Comment: And how you write to DB using mod_xml_cdr? mod_xml_cdr is for sending requests via HTTP.

Comment: I am new at FS so i dont know.. Can you help me?